# Multiple condition formula using and, or, true, false

Tags: excel

The current formula I'm using below results in an error.

1.) The value in cell `'Required Info'!$D$90 = represents a numeric or a combination of alpha numeric and special characters; for anything less than 3 characters the result should = FALSE. E.g., the cell input could be $1,000,000 or 1M or $1M

2.) The value in `B106` is conditional where TRUE = Canada.

3.) The value in C111 is conditional where a cell is selected, C111 = TRUE

For context, If B106 = TRUE AND C111 = TRUE OR B106 = TRUE AND C111 = TRUE AND 'Required Info'!$D$90`>= 3 characters the result should be FALSE.

```
=IF((LEN('Required Info'!$D$90)>=3,'Required Info'!$D$90>=C111,OR(AND(B106=TRUE,(LEN('Required Info'!$D$90)<=3),TRUE)))
```

Comment: So you're checking the length of D90 and whether B106 is True. How does C111 fit in? Think you need to explain your requirements more clearly.

Comment: Try using a list instead of long paragraphs to list the requirements -- it will make things clearer for everyone

Comment: 1.) 'Required Info'!$D$90 identifies numerical, alpha numerical & special character.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54562340/edit)  instead of adding a lot of info in comments

Comment: With no context, I can't make heads or tail of what you say. Please take the time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: your patience is appreciated; I'm trying to simplify this as much as possible